# how to print some regression info on a figure

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(How = c(3.1e-05, 0.000114, 0.000417, 0.00153, 
0.00561, 0.0206, 0.0754, 0.277, 1.01, 3.72), Where = c(1, 0.948118156866697, 
0.920303987764611, 1.03610743904536, 1.08332987533419, 0.960086785898477, 
0.765642506120658, 0.572520170014998, 0.375835106792894, 0.254180720963181
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

library(drc)
```

I make my model like this

```
fit <- drm(formula = Where ~ How, data = df, 
           fct = LL.4(names=c("Slope","Lower Limit","Upper Limit", "EC50")))
```

Then I plot it like this

```
plot(NULL, xlim = c(0.000001, 4), ylim = c(0.01, 1.2),log = "x")
  points(df$How, df$Where, pch = 20)
  x1 = seq(0.000001, 4, by=0.0001)
  y1 = coef(fit)[3] + (coef(fit)[2] - coef(fit)[3])/(1+(x1/coef(fit)[4])^((-1)*coef(fit)[1]))
  lines(x1,y1)
```

Now I want to be able to print the following information inside the figure

```
max(df$How)
min(df$How)
coef(fit)[2]
coef(fit)[3]
(-1)*coef(fit)[1]
coef(fit)[4]
```

I tried to do it like this

```
text(labels = bquote(FirstT~"="~.(round(max(df$How)))))
text(labels = bquote(SecondT~"="~.(round(min(df$How))))
text(labels = bquote(A[min]~"="~.(round(coef(fit)[2]))))
text(labels = bquote(A[max]~"="~.(coef(fit)[3]))))    
text(labels = paste0("Slope = ", round((-1)*coef(fit)[1])))
```

which of course does not work. I am more into an automatic way to find a place in right left corner of the figure that print these info

Comment: Does something like the following do what you intend: `text(max(df$How), df$Where[which.max(df$How)], labels = bquote(FirstT~"="~.(round(max(df$How)))), 
     pos=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below, we get the plot area coordinate ranges with `par("usr")` and then use those and the data point locations to automatically place the labels in the desired locations.

```
# Reduce margins
par(mar=c(5,4,0.5,0.5))

# Get extreme coordinates of plot area
p = par("usr")
p[1:2] = 10^p[1:2] # Because xscale is logged

text(max(df$How), df$Where[which.max(df$How)], 
     labels = bquote(FirstT~"="~.(round(max(df$How)))), pos=1)
text(min(df$How), df$Where[which.min(df$How)], 
     labels = bquote(SecondT~"="~.(round(min(df$How)))), pos=1)
text(1.1*p[1], p[3] + 0.02*diff(p[3:4]), 
     labels = bquote(A[min]~"="~.(round(coef(fit)[2]))), adj=c(0,0))
```

[image]